# Add iteration value in a function with a loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to create a function that contains a loop, which purpose is to get the predictions from a list of models. I'm a total newbie with loops... I guess that this might be easily done with purrr or apply family functions, however I'm stuck in getting in the proper way.

```
pred_getter<-function(testset,...){
  for(i in list(...)){
df<-data.frame(predict(fit_xgb,testdf,type = "prob")[1])
return(df)
}
}
pred_getter(testdf,fit_xgb,fit_glm,fit_lgt)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider passing in a character list of models and then build a list of predicted values data frames with `lapply` using `get` on name of object. Finally, concatenate list of data frames for final object:

```
pred_getter <- function(testset, models) {
    # GENERATE NAMED LIST OF DATA FRAMES
    df_list <- lapply(models, function(m) 
                    data.frame(model = m,
                               prediction = predict(get(m), testset, type = "prob")[1])
               )

    # BUILD SINGLE DATA FRAME OF ALL MODELS
    pred_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df_list)
}


final_df <- pred_getter(testdf, c("fit_xgb", "fit_glm", "fit_lgt"))
```

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!